# laravel port is changing automatically?

Tags: php, laravel, vue-cli

laravel port changing automatically after i started my server the server is restarted each time i refresh the page or move to another page the port is changing

`(http://127.0.0.1:8000 => http://127.0.0.1:8001 =>...........)`

even when i used the option `--port` the server stopped from running

i am running

```
Laravel Framework 8.11.2
PHP 7.4.9
@vue/cli 4.5.9
Ubuntu machine
```

Comment: Did you try with sudo?